# Overriding in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, model-view-controller, angular-ui-router, ng-controller

I have two controllers which are nested:

```
Controller A {

   $scope.submitForm = submitForm;

}
```

And

```
Controller B {

   function submitForm() {

      //Will this method be invoked? When there is a submit event fired in controller A?

   }

}
```

Note:
Controller A and B are nested, i.e B is inside A.

Comment: The best way to invoke a function in another controller is to use `rootscope and then the scope.on function`

Comment: This is just a statement. What is the question? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:
in controller b

```
$rootScope.$on('myFunctionInContollerb', function () {

});
```

in the controller calling the function

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('myFunctionInContollerb')
```

this is probably the easiest way to communicate in between controllers

Answer (score 0):

If you're using angular 1.6 or greater I encourage you to check out the component method instead of controller. Controllers using scope inheritance are considered legacy approach. Components even have example for child components using routes.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component